# Find all the elements which have the first child of td with inner text of `xxx`?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm use html agility pack to parse a html file. There is a big table in the html file.

```
....
<tr class="..."><td>xxx</td>.....</tr>
<tr class="..."><td>xxx</td>.....</tr>
<tr class="..."><td>yyy</td>.....</tr>
<tr class="..."><td>zzz</td>.....</tr>
....
```

I want to select all the `tr`s which have the first child `td` with inner text of `xxx`. How to write the xpath?

```
//tr[....]
```

**Update:**

How to add an additional condition of "the `tr`s must also have exactly five `td`s"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//tr[td[1][. = 'xxx']]
```

***Update:***

```
//tr[td[1][. = 'xxx']][count(td) = 5]
```

or using `and` operand:

```
//tr[td[1][. = 'xxx'] and count(td) = 5]
```

Comment: Thanks. How to add an additional condition of "the tr must also have exactly five `td`s"?

Comment: I'm surprised  there is not `and` for updated question. Curious how to handle it if the two condition need `or` instead of `and`?